# javax.persistence and jakarta.persistence classpath errors

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have a springboot project that uses jpa and olingo. It runs ok locally for testing but when I create a war file and run it, I sometimes get this error

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindJoinedTableAssociation(AnnotationBinder.java:2531)

The following method did not exist:

javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

The method's class, javax.persistence.JoinTable, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/spring-boot-doeapis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/javax.persistence-2.0.5.jar!/javax/persistence/JoinTable.class
jar:file:/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/spring-boot-doeapis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/JoinTable.class

It was loaded from the following location:

file:/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/spring-boot-doeapis-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/javax.persistence-2.0.5.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.JoinTable
```

Now I'm trying to figure out which one of the libraries I'm using is downloading the javax.persistence or jakarata.persistence so I can try to prevent it from downloading. I'm using Maven if it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <olingo2.version>2.0.11</olingo2.version>
        <sap.cloud.sdk.version>3.99.14</sap.cloud.sdk.version>
    </properties>

    <groupId>gov.doe.ph</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-doeapis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-doeapis</name>
    <description>Doe project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!--properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <olingo2.version>2.0.11</olingo2.version>
    </properties-->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!--exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion-->
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo-java-web-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${sap.cloud.sdk.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Olingo 2 Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo2.version}</version>
            <!-- Avoid jax-rs version conflict by excluding Olingo's version -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-ref</artifactId>
            <version>${olingo2.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 For unable to acquire JDBC connection error-->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency-->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
        </dependency-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!--plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.apache.olingo.odata2.core.rest.ODataExceptionMapperImpl</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.shaded.plexus.util</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>cf</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>neo</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I tried to remove every library little by little so long as it still compiles but I still get both jar files so now I want know how to check what jar files each fo my libraries downloads.

Update: It seems that spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is the one that gets the jakarta.persistence and the olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-core, olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-ref and hibernate-testing are the ones using the javax.persistence.
I've only been using spring boot for a short while so would this actually cause problems? Thing is, I don't get the error consistently. When I restart the server, sometimes I get the error and other times I don't. I can't really figure out what causes the error to appear.

Answer (score 2):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` and find which dependencies depends on javax.persistence and jakarta.persistence.

Then you have to make a decision. Do you want to use javax or jakarta?.

If you want to use javax, you will need to decrease the version of libraries that depends on persistence till you find javax from previous command. If you want to use jakarta you will need to increase that versions.

The important thing is that all dependencies are consistent with javax or jakarta.